# Function returning undefined in try block

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My code is currently returning as 'undefined';

```
function findDoc(rowObj) {
  Database.findOne(
    { 'name': rowObj.name },
    '_id, foreign_id'
  ).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
return docs;
  });
}

try {
      console.log('before');
      let searchDoc = await findDoc(rowObj);
      console.log(searchDoc);
      console.log('after');
} catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
}
```

This outputs;

```
before
undefined
after
```

whereas if i change the `findDoc` function to `console.log(docs);` rather than `return docs` i get;

```
before
CORRECT OBJECT
after
```

How can i fix this to get the second result using the first structure where it returns to the main try catch block?

Thanks

Comment: put await before `return await Database.findOne(` and wrap function with async `async function findDoc(rowObj) {`

Comment: I accidently posted the code with `return Database.findOne...` I have updated this now. I've also tried the code above with async/await but to the same result

Comment: It works without the async/await if I directly use `return Database...` rather than chaining `.exec()` to handle errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either wrap your function with async or use a callback as follows :

```
function findDoc(rowObj,callback) {
  Database.findOne(
       { 'name': rowObj.name },
       '_id, foreign_id'
  ).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
       throw err;
  } else {
       callback(docs);
  });
}

try {
  console.log('before');
  findDoc(rowObj,(searchDoc) => {
    console.log(searchDoc);
    console.log('after');
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```